# Shift the decimal places in SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, floating-point

I have 1500+ rows in my SQL Server 2005 database, in a table. The column is a PK of type `float`.

The data is like :

```
130226.1 
130226.2 
.... 
130226.9
```

What I want to do is : convert it to

```
130226.001
130226.002
```

Is there an efficient way to do this?

Please advise.

Comment: What happens with a number like this `130226.134`? It becomes `130226.00134`?

Comment: or 1.3677899 e-22 ...

Comment: Float as primary key. Cue music I see trouble ahead...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do:

```
Update table1 set column1 = floor(column1) + (Column1 - floor(column1)) / 100
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c2119/6)

Answer (score 0):

Use something like `DECIMAL(13,3)` allows  10 digits before the decimal point and 3 digits after the decimal point